# Distinct by year doesn't remove all my multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I got this code:

```
var sales = SalesData();

var distinctedList = sales.DistinctBy(x => x.InsertDate.Year).ToList();

return View(distinctedList);
```

SalesData gets all data and puts it to the sales list.
I'm printing out my years into tabs, but it doesn't remove all double/multiple values.

It removes all double/multiple values from 12 years, except 2.
For example it looks like this now:

[image]

But I want it like this:

[image]

-Also all the years have multiple values, so I don't know why this two doesn't get distincted (2018 has about 14 values, 2009 has around 50 values, 2011 has around 50 too).....

Comment: What are the results of the items returned for 2018 and 2009?

Comment: Is it possible the tabs are using a different date for display? If they aren't using InsertDate then I could see this behaving exactly as you are seeing.

Comment: Where is `DistinctBy` defined?

Comment: `sales.Select(x => x.InsertDate.Year).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: @RufusL Hopefully it's the MoreLinq version.

Comment: Assuming you're using [MoreLINQ DistinctBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs), it's working as expected for me. Do you have some sample data, and some code that shows how you're populating the tabs?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get distinct years only, then you can use this:

```
var distinctedYears = sales.GroupBy(x => x.InsertDate.Year).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

In addition to distinct years, if you need `sales` to be grouped by the year then you can do something like:

```
var groupedSales = sales.GroupBy(x => x.InsertDate.Year).ToList();
var distinctedYears = groupedSales.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: it didn't work because I'm using a dynamic viewmodel, so it gives me an int :-)